# Зачем в meteor js 1.5 вставки import?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Во всех файлах по умолчанию указывается вначале:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
```

И тому подобное.

Но и без этой вставки всё работает. Зачем meteor то это понадобилось... Это нужно для IDE, для производительности или ещё для чего? Не могу понять.

Расскажите, пожалуйста, буду очень признателен :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Глобальный объект `Meteor` и другие оставлены для обратной совместимости с прошлыми версиями. Писать везде этот импорт нужно потому что:

1. Отказ от глобальных переменных -- правильный подход: явный импорт упрощает чтение кода, уменьшает количество ошибок.
2. В одном из последующих релизов глобальные переменные, такие как объект `Meteor`, могу попросту убрать и после обновления ваше приложение перестанет работать, если вы использовали глобальные переменные без импорта.

Comment: Как, кстати, в метеор сейчас обстоят дела с обновлением? Читал что очень плохо. Это было давно, а как сейчас, получше? При обновлении много нужно решать проблем? Интересно как в крупных проектах, хотя и в небольших - разумеется.

Comment: @СергейСавельев с 1.3 особых проблем с обновлением не помню. В обновлениях сейчас в основном новые фичи и багфиксы.

Comment: Скажи, проекты, которые ты обновлял, на сколько крупные? Примерно из скольки файлов? Какая посещаемость?

Comment: Просто если это сотни файлов, как то очень будет неудобно...

Comment: 150-200 файлов, посмотрите историю версий, по ней понятней будет что менять https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md

Comment: Это сложно уловить из данного ответа, по этому напишу. Если в одном файле указать import varName './../imports/utils.js', то импортируемый файл будет доступным лишь для данного файла. Кстати, с import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor' так же?

Comment: Да только в этом файле